# Qual linguagem corresponde a "Foundation"?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Já fiz essa pergunta anteriormente, porém não estava claro o suficiente, então explicarei novamente.

Estou aprendendo Objective-C com um livro. Porém, este livro é antigo, e nele, o autor do livro usa a versão 4.3 do Xcode. 
Logo no início, ele ensina como criar um novo projeto no Xcode (muito fácil).[image: Segue imagem de como ele cria no Xcode 4.3]

Quando fui seguir esses passos no Xcode 7.1.1, na área "Type/Tipo", não encontrei a opção "Foundation" que ele manda selecionar, não existe esse tipo "Foundation", apenas Objective-C, Swift, C e C++. 
Qual dessas linguagens corresponde a Foundation? Seria objective-c? Qual a diferença?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Até aonde sei Foundation é um framework html/css que pode ser usado em qualquer linguagem ou ambiente, ou seja ele não corresponde a nenhuma linguagem citada, ele simplesmente pode ser aplicado a qualquer ambiente que tenha um webView. Realmente não entendo muito bem a sua pergunta, se existe outro Foundation ou coisa do genero, desculpe mas é melhor você começar a estudar livros mais recentes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Foundation no mundo Objective-c refere-se ao framework principal/base da linguagem.

Answer (score 1):

No momento que este livro foi escrito só existtia Objective-C portanto tipo "Foundation" pode ser considerado código escrito em Objective-C.

Como você está trabalhando com Xcode 7 então você deve escolher entre Swift ou Objective-C. Esta escolha será puramente baseada na linguagem que você deseja aprender no momento.

Recomendo fortemente utilizar tutoriais mais atualizados.

Bons blogs (Em inglês):

[www.raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com)

[www.nshipster.com](http://www.nshipster.com)

Comment: Valeu Otávio, vou dar uma olhada pois sei inglês.